# Syntax error when defining a map under a http-snippet in nginx chart

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have a question related to Kubernetes Ingress-nginx, I want to use [ngx_http_map_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) to define a new attribute for [log-format-upstream](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/log-format/). The respective part in [helm chart](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/) where I have defined my map looks like this:

```
containerPort:
   http: 80
   https: 443
 
 config:
   log-format-upstream: $time_iso8601, $proxy_protocol_addr, $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for, $req_id, $remote_user, $bytes_sent, $request_time, $status, $host, $server_protocol, $uri $uri_category

   http-snippet: |
       map $uri $uri_category {
        ~(*/)([0-9]{3,}+)(/*)$ $2;
        }

 configAnnotations: {}
```

However, it gives me following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] unexpected "{" in /tmp/nginx-cfg1517276787:255
```

The line 255 in the config looks like this:

```
 proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
 map $uri $uri_category { #Line: 255
 ~(*/)([0-9]{3,}+)(/*)$ $2;
 }
 
 upstream upstream_balancer {
```

I doubt that i havent defined `http-snippet` and map at the right location in the chart, but i am not sure where exactly it should be either?

Comment: The regex is missing escape "\" characters. I can't tell what exactly what you want to replace, e.g. do you want any of these two `-~` characters to be converted to a `1`?

When I test that map declaration, I get: `nginx: [emerg] invalid number of the map parameters`

Comment: @EricFortis fixed the regex, had been trying multiple patterns so. However, the issue and error is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49440631): Surround the regex in double-quotes; Nginx uses `{` and `}` for defining blocks.

For example:

```
  map $uri $uri_category {
    "~[0-9]{3,}" 'FOO';
  }

  server {
    location / {
      try_files $uri$uri_category =404;
    }
  }
```

That config appends `'FOO'` to three+ consecutive digits.

```
/123  -> /123FOO
/4444 -> /4444FOO
```

---

In your case, I think the regex should be something like:

`"~(.*/)([0-9]{3,})(/.*)$" $2;`